# Copy rows to another worksheet based on 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vba

Have a document that grows in length daily. I'd like to archive rows that contain both an invoice amount (I'm thinking Col D ISNUMBER) and a 0 balance by moving them to a second sheet in the workbook. My question is twofold: what code do I need to do this, and can the macro run actively (meaning that when both conditions are satisfied the row is automatically moved to the second sheet), or do I need to add a button to run the macro daily? Data set is as follows, I'd like the macro to take lines 2 & 4 out to archive them:

```
Date    Client    Inv#    Inv Amt    Deposit    Payment    Balance
9/2/14  ABC       1003    $500                  $500       $0
9/4/14  ABC       1004    $400                             $400
9/4/14  DEF       1005    $1000      $1000                 $0
9/5/14  DEF       1006    $4500      $2000                 $2500
9/5/14  ABC       1007    $650                             $650
9/6/14  GHI       1008    $2500      $1500                 $1000
9/6/14  ABC       1009    $800
```

Comment: There are already so many examples of this on SO http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Copy+rows+to+another+worksheet

Comment: I looked through them before posting and couldn't find anything looking for 2 criteria

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following

Sheet1 contains the data to filter. Sheet2 is an **empty** sheet that you will be pasting data into. That we are going to do error correction for the presence of the header

```
Public Sub MoveSomeStuff()
    Const intDateOffset As Integer = 1
    Const intBalanceOffset As Integer = 7
    Const intInventoryAmountOffset As Integer = 4

    Dim objSingleRow As Range
    Dim objUsedRows As Range
    Dim objEmptyRow As Range
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet

    Dim singleBalance As Long
    Dim singleInventoryAmount As Long

    Set wsDestination = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set objUsedRows = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows

    ' Stop screen updating while the code is processing. Will speed it up.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Cycle through every row that is used.
    For Each objSingleRow In objUsedRows

        ' Gather Inventory Amount and Balance
        singleBalance = IIf((IsNumeric(objSingleRow.Cells(, intBalanceOffset).Value) And (objSingleRow.Cells(, intBalanceOffset).Value <> "")), objSingleRow.Cells(, intBalanceOffset).Value, -1)
        singleInventoryAmount = IIf((IsNumeric(objSingleRow.Cells(, intInventoryAmountOffset).Value) And (objSingleRow.Cells(, intInventoryAmountOffset).Value <> "")), objSingleRow.Cells(, intInventoryAmountOffset).Value, -1)


        ' Determine if this row should be copied
        If (objSingleRow.Cells(, intDateOffset).Value = "Date") Or _
                ((singleInventoryAmount > 0) And (singleBalance = 0)) Then
            ' Copy the row to the clipboard
            objSingleRow.Copy

            With wsDestination
                ' If the sheet has not data just paste in the first row.
                If .Range("A1") = "" Then
                    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                Else
                    ' Locate the next empty row that we can paste into.
                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next

    ' Resume screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Cycle through all the used rows from `Sheet1`

`singleBalance` and `singleInventoryAmount` are the respective values of that particular row. They are checked to see if they are both numbers and not blank. `IsNumeric` returned true for me on a blank cell.

Edit the lines to suit your needs

```
Set wsDestination = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set objUsedRows = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows
```

Copy a row based if it contains the header or if it contains and `singleInventoryAmount` and a zero `singleBalance`

**Output on Sheet2**

```
Date    Client  Inv#    Inv Amt Deposit Payment Balance
9/2/2014    ABC 1003    500     500 0
9/4/2014    DEF 1005    1000    1000        0
```